# alfresco - how to add a nodeRef as the new version of another node using java?

Tags: alfresco

Hi I am new to alfresco so i appreciate your help.
I am trying to add a new node ref as the new version of a document while editing his properties.
My scenario
i can create a PDF file with his properties as the content,after updating his properties, I am doing this with behavior/policies NodeServicePolicies.OnUpdateNodePolicy .
example: when i edit the name I can see it inside the PDF file

But this new file needs to be the new version of the file edited, i cant figure how to fix this.
i appreciate yours answer.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/concepts/versioning.html

You're looking for versioning.
Like Curtis mentioned, using API is an option, but Alfresco will do this for you automatically if you set it up that way. Also, creating a new version will not change node's nodeRef.

Comment: thank you for answering me, but i want to know how i can make this new file the new version. so it can be referenced in the version history.

Comment: i have this method

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. So simply by changing metadata and/or content you will get a new version, and a new node in version history.

Comment: for example in a method  void(NodeRef nodeA , NodeRef nodeB)   i want to make nodeB the new version of nodeA. how can i achieve this result?

Comment: Thanks @Lista
i just added get the content of the new file and set as the new content of the previous node. 
like this

void updateVersionWithNewNodeContent(nodeA){
// nodeB is the new version of the file.
NodeRef nodeB; 

 nodeService.setProperty(nodeA, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT,nodeService.getProperty(nodeB, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT));  
}

Answer (score 1):

See the createVersion method from the VersionService API [here](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/dev-services-version.html)

Answer (score 0):

My fix:

i just added get the content of the new file and set as the new content of the previous node. like this

```
void updateVersionWithNewNodeContent(nodeA){ // nodeB is the new version of the file. NodeRef nodeB; nodeService.setProperty(nodeA, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT,nodeService.getProperty(nodeB, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT)); }
```